# How to prevent closing Navigation drawer by touch outside the drawer

Tags: android, touch, navigation-drawer

I have an Activity with Navigation Drawer. if user device is table and orientation is landscape - I not need to close drawer by click on item in drawer:

```
if (!isTablet || context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==1) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
}
```

It work. But if user touch the screen outside opened drawer - drawer closing. 
Using DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN is unsuitable bacause I need to save drawer sliding functions.
**How to prevent closing Navigation drawer when user touch outside the drawer?**

Please, help.

Comment: Just so you know, doing that goes against [Android Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

_When the navigation drawer is expanded, the user can dismiss it in one of four ways:

Touching the content outside the navigation drawer
Swiping to the left anywhere on the screen (including edge swipe from right)
Touching the app icon/title in the action bar
Pressing Back_

Comment: I concur, the user expects this behavior, when you take it away, they're gonna be pissed.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I understand this but it is product requirement.

Comment: @Anton Stukov Have you found answer for your question?

Comment: No, not found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the other answer which I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34287179/1118772). I have modified the code to suit your question. Please check.

Check more about touch hierarchy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15744974/1118772)

`dispatchTouchEvent()` method should be overridden in `Activity` class

```
@Override    
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (isDrawerOpen()) { //Your code here to check whether drawer is open or not. 

            View content = findViewById(R.id.drawer); //drawer view id
            int[] contentLocation = new int[2];
            content.getLocationOnScreen(contentLocation);
            Rect rect = new Rect(contentLocation[0],
                contentLocation[1],
                contentLocation[0] + content.getWidth(),
                contentLocation[1] + content.getHeight());

            if (!(rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()))) {
                isOutSideClicked = true;
            } else {
                isOutSideClicked = false;
            }

        } else {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && isOutSideClicked) {
        isOutSideClicked = false;
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && isOutSideClicked) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    if (isOutSideClicked) {
        return true; //restrict the touch event here
    }else{
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

**Note: As mentioned in the question comments, this is against of [Android guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#). So try to avoid it until unless it is mandatory.**

Answer (score 4):

Simplified version of Noundla's answer which works for me. I wrote my custom Drawer which extends `DrawerLayout` and implement `dispatchTouchEvent()` method.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!this.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
    boolean isOutSideClicked = false;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        View content = findViewById(R.id.drawer_view); 
        int[] contentLocation = new int[2];
        content.getLocationOnScreen(contentLocation);
        Rect rect = new Rect(contentLocation[0],
                contentLocation[1],
                contentLocation[0] + content.getWidth(),
                contentLocation[1] + content.getHeight());
        isOutSideClicked = !(rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));
    }
    this.setDrawerLockMode(isOutSideClicked ? DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN : DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Also if you want to keep interact with main content fragment while drawer is open you should add this line at the beginning of the method.

```
getChildAt(0).dispatchTouchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 2):

it very simple use your drawer instance to prevent

**1. implement DrawerLayout.DrawerListener**

**2. add this single statement inside this method us**

```
 @Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);//DrawerLayout instance
}
```

Comment: This answer is really helpful & very simple to use, only you need to handle click action for open & close drawer. When the drawer opens use DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN & when the drawer is closed use DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED