# How to detect the touch event outside the navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I have implemented Android Navigation drawer in my application. I am able to open/close the drawer when user touches the out side of navigation drawer. Can any one of you help me in detect the touch/click event when user touch/click out side the navigation drawer. I need to perform some functionality in that event.
Please check the attached screenshot.[image]
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: same issue in my case also found any solution for this, b'coz in my case below acceptable answer is not working.

Answer (score 8):

You have to handle the touch position in `dispatchTouchEvent()` method. Check more about touch hierarchy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15744974/1118772)

```
@Override    
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mRightDrawerListView)) {

            View content = findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
            int[] contentLocation = new int[2];
            content.getLocationOnScreen(contentLocation);
            Rect rect = new Rect(contentLocation[0],
                contentLocation[1],
                contentLocation[0] + content.getWidth(),
                contentLocation[1] + content.getHeight());

            View toolbarView = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            int[] toolbarLocation = new int[2];
            toolbarView.getLocationOnScreen(toolbarLocation);
            Rect toolbarViewRect = new Rect(toolbarLocation[0],
                toolbarLocation[1],
                toolbarLocation[0] + toolbarView.getWidth(),
                toolbarLocation[1] + toolbarView.getHeight());


            if (!(rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) && !toolbarViewRect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
                isOutSideClicked = true;
            } else {
                isOutSideClicked = false;
            }

        } else {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && isOutSideClicked) {
        isOutSideClicked = false;
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && isOutSideClicked) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    if (isOutSideClicked) {
        //make http call/db request
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may spend some time by checking this out.

[DrawerLayout.DrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)

I hope it will help you as it helps me.

An example:

```
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onDrawerClosed`

> when you touch outside screen `onDrawerClosed` will call after close of Navigation
>   Drawer

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            //do  here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. onDrawerClosed(View view) will call in many scenarios. that will not work for me.

Comment: may be help [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590247/android-navigation-drawer-doesnt-pass-ontouchevent-to-activity)