# a pop-out menu in a DrawerLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have created a DrawerLayout with a right side drawer. So far, so good. Now, there's one menu item which, when clicked opens a pop-out menu with 5 different options (see screenshot). When one of the options is clicked the icon in the main menu should get swapped for the icon that I just clicked and *then* the main menu should close. However, I have not been able to create that behaviour. Currently when I try to click one of the options in the pop-out menu the following happens:
 1. The main menu (the drawer) closes.
 2. Only if I click the desired option *again* the icon in the main menu gets swapped.
As far as I understand this it is the default behaviour of a drawer within a DrawerView to be closed as soon as I click somewhere in the screen. I have tried to work around it by setting the lock mode:

```
myDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN, Gravity.END)
```

... but no luck. The drawer closes as soon as I try to click one of the items in the pop-out.
Is it even possible to achieve what I want in a DrawerLayout?

[image: pop-out menu]

Here's my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.videosc2.activities.VideOSCMainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera_downscaled"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:antialias="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/preview_image_content_description"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the right (layout_gravity:end) -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:background="#99000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/tool"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
           android:contentDescription="@string/a_tools_menu_item"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:paddingBottom="8dp"
           android:paddingLeft="8dp"
           android:paddingRight="8dp"
           android:paddingTop="8dp"/>
```

color_mode_panel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/color_mode_panel"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="end"
              android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
              android:background="#99000000"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mode_rgb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/color_mode_rgb"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rgb"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mode_rgb_inv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/color_mode_rgb_neg"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rgb_inv"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mode_r"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/color_mode_r"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/r"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mode_g"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/color_mode_g"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/g"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mode_b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/color_mode_b"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/b"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    View camView;
    public static Point dimensions;
    private DrawerLayout toolsDrawerLayout;
    private FrameLayout mainFrame;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    protected ArrayList<View> uiElements = new ArrayList<>();

    // is device currently sending OSC?
    public boolean isPlaying = false;
    // is flashlight on?
    public boolean isTorchOn = false;
    // don't create more than one color mode panel
    private boolean isColorModePanelOpen = false;

    public Fragment cameraPreview;
    Camera camera;

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (findViewById(R.id.camera_preview) != null) {
            camView = findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

            if (savedInstanceState != null) return;
            cameraPreview = new VideOSCCameraFragment();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.camera_preview, cameraPreview, "CamPreview")
                    .commit();
        }

        TypedArray tools = getResources().obtainTypedArray(drawer_icons_id);
        toolsDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toolsDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        // FIXME: touches seem to get swallowed by the DrawerLayout first
        final ListView toolsDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        List<BitmapDrawable> toolsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tools.length(); i++) {
            toolsList.add((BitmapDrawable) tools.getDrawable(i));
        }

        // set the drawer menu in a custom Adapter
        toolsDrawerList.setAdapter(new ToolsMenuAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_item, R.id.tool, toolsList));
        tools.recycle();

        toolsDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                BitmapDrawable img;
                final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tool);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                // we can not use 'cameraPreview' to retrieve the 'mCamera' object
                VideOSCCameraFragment camPreview = (VideOSCCameraFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("CamPreview");
                camera = camPreview.mCamera;
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

                switch (i) {
                    // ... other cases...
                    case 2:
                        if (!isColorModePanelOpen) {
                            int y = (int) view.getY();
                            // create pop-out
                            final View modePanel = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_mode_panel, (FrameLayout) camView, true);
                            isColorModePanelOpen = true;
                            // try to lock the main menu drawer - didn't work for me
                            toolsDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN, toolsDrawerList);

                            final View modePanelInner = modePanel.findViewById(R.id.color_mode_panel);
                            // set the vertical position of the pop-out
                            ActivityHelpers.setMargins(modePanelInner, 0, y, 0, 0);
                            // set actions for each item in the pop-out 
                            for (int k = 0; k < ((ViewGroup) modePanelInner).getChildCount(); k++) {
                                final Context iContext = context;

                                View button = ((ViewGroup) modePanelInner).getChildAt(k);
                                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    // FIXME: touches seem to get swallowed by the DrawerLayout first
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        switch (view.getId()) {
                                            case R.id.mode_rgb:
                                                Log.d(TAG, "rgb");
                                                imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(iContext, R.drawable.rgb));
                                                break;
                                            case R.id.mode_rgb_inv:
                                                Log.d(TAG, "rgb inverted");
                                                imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(iContext, R.drawable.rgb_inv));
                                                break;
                                            case R.id.mode_r:
                                                Log.d(TAG, "red");
                                                imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(iContext, R.drawable.r));
                                                break;
                                            case R.id.mode_g:
                                                Log.d(TAG, "green");
                                                imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(iContext, R.drawable.g));
                                                break;
                                            case R.id.mode_b:
                                                Log.d(TAG, "blue");
                                                imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(iContext, R.drawable.b));
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(iContext, R.drawable.rgb));
                                        }
                                        // remove the pop-out
                                        ((ViewGroup) modePanelInner.getParent()).removeView(modePanelInner);
                                        isColorModePanelOpen = false;
                                        // unlock the drawer again
                                        toolsDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, Gravity.END);
                                        // now the drawer should finally get closed
                                        toolsDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
                                   }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    // ... other cases ...
                }
            });

            // open drawer on application start
            toolsDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626218/how-to-prevent-closing-navigation-drawer-by-touch-outside-the-drawer) that offered me a simple way of preventing my pop-out from being closed by adding the following to my MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // We only want to intercept MotionEvent.ACTION_UP if the pop-out is present
    return !(isColorModePanelOpen && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) && super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

That worked in so far as the drawer is not being closed immediately when trying to click one of the buttons in the pop-out. Unfortunately, the buttons don't accept clicks (resp. touches with an event action MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) either. It seems, as long as the drawer isn't closed again, the whole screen is being blocked from any user interaction.

Can anyone confirm my suspicion? (or prove me wrong)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in `onResume()` of your Activity

```
if(condition)
{
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
}
else
{
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
}
```

Comment: That didn't have the desired effect - unfortunately. Thanks.