# Call onBackPressed inside a private class in Kotlin

Tags: android, class, kotlin, gesture

I'm trying to create a gesture detector class by following the guide on the Android Developers [website](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector), but I'm stuck because I cannot invoke the method onBackPressed() inside the new private class created by me. How can I manage it? This is my code:

```
    class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mDetector: GestureDetectorCompat

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_activity)

        mDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, MyGestureListener())
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private class MyGestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        private val SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100
        private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100

        override fun onDown(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            //CALL onBackPressed
            return true
        }

        override fun onFling(
                event1: MotionEvent,
                event2: MotionEvent,
                velocityX: Float,
                velocityY: Float
        ): Boolean {
            //TODO
            var distanceX = event2.getX() - event1.getX()
            var distanceY = event2.getY() - event1.getY()
            if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (distanceX > 0)
                //CALL onBackPressed
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

New code:

```
    class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mDetector: GestureDetectorCompat

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_activity)

        mDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, MyGestureListener())
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

    inner class MyGestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        private val SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100
        private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100

        override fun onDown(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            System.out.println("LOGG")
            this@DetailActivity.onBackPressed()
            return true
        }

        override fun onFling(
                event1: MotionEvent,
                event2: MotionEvent,
                velocityX: Float,
                velocityY: Float
        ): Boolean {
            var distanceX = event2.getX() - event1.getX()
            var distanceY = event2.getY() - event1.getY()
            if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (distanceX > 0) {
                    System.out.println("LOGG")
                    this@DetailActivity.onBackPressed()
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I added a new method **onBackPressed** and I invoked it through the inner class, but nothing changed. I also doesn't see the prints in my Logcat.

Comment: Only `class` implies to static nested class and `inner class` implies to non-static nested class in kotlin .  [See the Doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html).

Comment: I did it but it doesn't works. I updated the question with the new code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a `private inner class`.
In Kotlin nested classes are static by default. To make it an inner class, which can access properties of the enclosing class, you have to use the 'inner' keyword.

See [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Comment: I declared it as **inner**, then inside the two methods I added **this@DetailActivity.onBackPressed()** and a print to check if the programs enters inside these methods but even if it compile without errors nothing gets printed and the onbackpressed doesn't works.

Comment: If it compiles, then this question is answered. That the logic doesn't work as expected is something else to debug that I cannot answer immediately. Does the onFling method get called? Are you sure you should always return true? sometimes this means no further events are passed.

Comment: The methods inside the inner class doesn't get called. I tried to put prints to debug everywhere in the code but nothing works

Comment: Possibly the touch event is already claimed and does not bubble back to the Activity `onTouchEvent`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740948/activitys-ontouchevent-is-not-being-called-while-clicking-on-button