# Android: How to detect touch on clickable RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, touch, listener, clickable, ripple

I have a custom layout "MyLayout" which extends `RelativeLayout` and inflates `my_layout.xml`:

```java
public class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    // the constructors are all calling init(context);

    private void init(Context context) {
        if (context != null) {
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("touched");
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Here is `my_layout.xml` which has a ripple animation:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Now here is what happens when i change the value of `android:clickable`

| `android:clickable="false"` | `android:clickable="true"` |
| --- | --- |
| ripple animation won't show up | ripple animation works as intended |
| `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` will be called on touch | `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` is never called |

**How can i make both the ripple animation visible as well as `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` be called on touch?**

- Other attributes like `android:focusable` and so on don't have any effect on the visibility of the ripple animation
- OnTouchListener and OnClickListener are never called if `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: Do you need touch events or is receiving a click event enough?

Comment: Touch events would be best because i intend to detect double-tab and long-press via a `GestureDetector`

Comment: Also read this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740948/activitys-ontouchevent-is-not-being-called-while-clicking-on-button#comment38523849_15740948

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! I will post this solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [zoomega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11016652/zomega), who showed me this question: [Activity's onTouchEvent() is not being called while clicking on Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740948/activitys-ontouchevent-is-not-being-called-while-clicking-on-button).

I have adjusted my code as follows:

```java
public class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    // the constructors are all calling init(context);

    private void init(Context context) {
        if (context != null) {
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev); // Necessary in order to trigger the ripple animation!
        System.out.println("touched"); // The logic here (e.g. GestureDetector)
        return true;
    }
}
```

This way, both the ripple effect is displayed and `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` is called.